# Error in ruby code when running puppet agent run

Tags: puppet

When I run puppet agent -t on my server I get an error:

[image: below image is the output of my puppet agent using a command puppet agent -t]

The logs from the puppet-master look like this:

[image: logs output from my puppet master server]

Comment: [root@pm manifests]# pwd
/etc/puppet/manifests
[root@pm manifests]# ls
site.pp
[root@pm manifests]# cat site.pp
file {'testfile':
path => '/tmp/testfile',
ensure => present,
mode => 0640,
content => "I'm a test file.",
}

Comment: above is the file site.pp while i m trying to call using puppet agent -t

Comment: Looks like a long-obsolete version of Ruby. Use a Puppet AIO install instead.

Comment: i am using below ruby version

ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is an error caused by using Ruby 1.8.7, a long EOL version of Ruby. Puppet uses Ruby to compile catalogs, and CentOS 6's upstream uses 1.8.7 Ruby, which has been EOL for [3 years](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/).

The easiest way to fix this problem is to use Puppet 4 onwards, which packages it's own Ruby as part of the [all-in-one package](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.3/about_agent.html) (to avoid errors like this on systems that support older Ruby versions)